# OpenSceneGraph: how to check whether ogsText::Font supports a provided character?

Tags: unicode, fonts, openscenegraph

I am trying to check whether the font contains a glyph for a given character. To achieve this, I have loaded the font by `readFontFile()` and get a glyph of the character. Then, I wanted to check whether the glyph texture is available. I tried the next code

```
osg::ref_ptr<osgText::Font> font = osgText::readFontFile("path_to_fft_font_file");
auto glyph = font->getGlyph(std::make_pair(32.0f, 32.0f), charcode);
auto texture_info = glyph->getTextureInfo(osgText::ShaderTechnique::GREYSCALE);
```

For all char codes (that are really supported by the font and that are not) the `texture_info` is `nullptr`.

I also tried to check `glyph->getTotalDataSize()`. It gives **not** a zero value if the character is not supported by the font but the font contains a glyph for `none` Unicode (usually looks like ▯).

Is there a way to check if the `osgText::Font` object contains a non-none glyph for the given character?